# Installing Ubuntu with EVGA Nvidia 660 results in corrupted video output

Tags: system-installation, screen-corruption

Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a dual boot PC along side Windows 8.1 Pro x64.
When I get to the install screen the Ubuntu logo and the 4 Dots show up fine but when the desktop try's to load it is corrupted I only see layers of colors and an unrecognizable slanted desktop.

Is there a way to add the graphics driver to the USB Install? or is there a safe mode install?

System:

- Intel Core i5-2500K 3.3ghz Turbo Processor
- EVGA Nvidia 660 ti Graphics card 3GB/Mem
- 1st SSD OCZ 256GB Windows 8.1 Installed
- 2nd 10k Raptor Hard Drive 300GB dedicated for Ubuntu
- 16GB DDR3 Dual Channel
- Mother Board: EVGA Z68
- Monitor: DELL 24" 1920X1200 Using HDMI from Graphics Card to Display.

Comment: Use the [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) than you can install Nvidia drivers under "Additional Drivers".

Comment: I have no install of Ubuntu on the second HD, can't install it at all. Just have Win 8.1 on first SSD. That is the issue.

Comment: Did you tried other version of Ubuntu, like Kubuntu or Xubuntu?

Comment: Ok i misunderstood you. To boot the installer in a graphical "safe mode", enable the "nomodeset". Press F6, use arrow keys on the boot screen to select the option. Or you can use the [Minimal-CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) ( The Minimal CD uses a text-based installer like the Alternate CD)